# Install RVM with ruby - did this install correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

Typed in `$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

From the output it looks like it ran successfully:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   185  100   185    0     0    132      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   296
100 10009  100 10009    0     0   5244      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 75255
Please read and follow further instructions.
Press ENTER to continue.
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   125  100   125    0     0    261      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1168
100 1123k  100 1123k    0     0   760k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1366k

Installing RVM to /Users/themaktravels/.rvm/
Adding rvm PATH line to /Users/themaktravels/.bashrc /Users/themaktravels/.zshenv.
RVM sourcing line found in /Users/themaktravels/.bash_profile          
/Users/themaktravels/.zprofile.

# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.io/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm/
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues read output of 'rvm requirements' and/or 'rvm notes'

Installation of RVM in /Users/themaktravels/.rvm/ is almost complete:

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/themaktravels/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.



Installation of RVM in /Users/themaktravels/.rvm/ is almost complete:

* To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/themaktravels/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.
```

But can someone explain what is meant by run  `source /Users/themaktravels/.rvm/scripts/rvm`?

Am I being instructed to run that as a command?  Would I close my terminal windows and then open a new window.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It says run it in your open shell windows, with a *possibility* of needing to re-open them.

Comment: check the [official document](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) about installation. **Section 3: Reload shell configuration & test**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed RVM successfully according to the screen output.

You have to load the RVM settings(information) to your PATH, so that you just need to type `rvm` and the shell knows you are mentioning `/home/blabla.../.rvm/bin/rvm`, and run it successfully.

I suggest you to put this line of code into your ~/.bashrc   or ~/.bash_login file (depends on your Linux release version ) so that it will auto loaded once you login.